# Windows Service always listening on port8080, even when killed

Tags: windows, port, listener, rundll32

I have a problem when i start my application by Spring, the port 8080 is allready listening by a service, which is "rundll32.exe", apparently a legitime file from system32, but even when i kill it, it come back, here is my prompt commands:

```
tasklist | findstr 15448
rundll32.exe                 15448 Services                   0     56,592 K

netstat -ano | findstr 8080
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       15448

taskkill /F /pid 15448
SUCCESS: The process with PID 15448 has been terminated.

netstat -ano | findstr 8080
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9796

tasklist | findstr 9796
rundll32.exe                  9796 Services                   0     55,976 K
```

As you can see, the service always listening the port8080. I tried to search a solution but i did not find a similar problem on the internet. Have you any suggestion? (I killed the rundll32 process in the Services list, but nothing has change)

Comment: You killed it but the service manager automatically restarted it.  You need to work with the service manager, send a "stop service" command, and not just terminate the service worker (which will result in recovery logic)

Comment: Note that "How do I take port 8080 away from a program already using it?" and "How do I stop a service?" are computer administration questions, not computer programming questions.  (Once you reach the point where you know how to do it by hand, and want to write a program to do it, then it becomes a programming question again)  So the proper site is superuser.com not stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ok, the problem appear during spring-boot process, but yes it's definitively an administration issue. I will ask the question at superuser. Thank you. (i stoped the service but he is always listening)

Answer (score 0):

Many applications in Windows use dynamic-link library (DLL) files to do a great number of things , simply trying to kill this particular task may result in the task being automatically restarted as it may be a necessary task for applications that may be running. Specifically the rundll32.exe is used to launch functionality stored in shared dll files. This is a valid part of Windows, and normally should not cause a problem. However, if your system does not have a legitimate reason to be listening on port 8080 and your system is somehow corrupted try following this link [1] for reparation instructions.

[1] Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files : 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system